# On finding total number of non linear asymptotes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

**Prologue**:[On understanding the use of binomial theorem to find asymptotes of a real valued function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32ZtD.jpg)

So i understood how to obtain *non linear asymototes* of a function if any.
So how do you know if the function has more than one *non linear asymptote*? I mean look at the part of the graph "in the 3rd quadrant". How do i know it wont have any *non linear asymptote* "there"?

Here is the reference Question used on all my posts:

y =$$(x^3+2x+9)$$/$$(sqrt(4x^2+3x+2))$$

My asymptote obtained using long division

y=(x^2/2) -(3x/16) +(9/128)

Graph: [image: Graph of the function and obrained asymptote]

**Red line**: Original Function

**Black line**: Asymptote

Comment: I am planning to learn mathsjax next.

Comment: Most of mathjax $\equiv$ putting `$` around mathematical objects

Comment: Not sure on how to answer. There are an infinite number of possible non-linear asymptotes in the example you've given (and the same for a lot of other examples too).

Comment: How do you find an asymptote for the graph of the function in the "negetive part".

Comment: I'm not sure how you got it for the positive part, but surely using the same method while applying the idea $x\to-\infty$ instead of $x\to\infty$ will work?

Comment: Listen i expanded the denominator using binomial theorem and took the first three terms. Then did polynomial division .